# Changing number format in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using the library `sklearn` to get class probabilities and saving those class probabilities in a `csv` file using `numpy.savetxt`.

The format that is being saved in the `csv` file is:
`1.00E+00,  1.00E-01,   2.00E-01`.
However I want in the format as `1, 0.1, 0.2`.
How do I do that?

Comment: What code are you using to save to csv?

Comment: I am using `numpy.savetxt`

Comment: I think `np.savetxt(path, data, fmt='%1.1f')` should work see the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do with scikit learn, which produces just a float array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) supports a `fmt` param, for values with a single precision you can pass param `fmt=%1.1f` this should allow probability values in the format you desire.

Example:

```
In [4]:

a = np.random.randn(5)
a
Out[4]:
array([ 0.85185988, -0.85148163,  0.5456541 , -0.26908162, -0.11920702])

np.savetxt(r'c:\data\np.dat', a, fmt='%1.1f')
```

yields:

> 0.9
>   -0.9
>   0.5
>   -0.3
>   -0.1